# newton's method with $y=\arctan(x)$

Tags: calculus

"failure to converge" (the name of exercise)

so I have an equation $y=\arctan(x)$,
root of the function is $x=0$,
and $x_0=2$
and i need to calculate $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$.

I was trying to calculate it for several times and get different results all the times. 
$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_0)}{f'(x_0)}$$
we know that $f'(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$

so my second approximation $$x_1=x_0-\arctan(x_0)*(1+x_0^2)$$ $$x_1=2-(-0.4577)*5=4.2885$$
is it correct? 
if not where my mistake is?

Comment: $\arctan(2)$ is not computed correctly.

Comment: $\arctan(2) \simeq 1.1071$. You evaluated the cotangent $\cot(x) = \frac{1}{\tan(x)} \neq \tan^{-1}(x) = \arctan(x)$!!!